# Magento product export issue?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database

I have 22k products in my website. When I export products from admin, it shows error:

`This page isn’t working demotoday.info took too long to respond.HTTP ERROR 504`

I have changed max_execution_time and memory_limit on the server but still the result is same.

When I checked the log file, in which an error related to the database.

```
2017-07-17T14:49:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=9539  in /var/www/html/staging/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: In error demotoday.info. What is this related to?

Comment: this is demo server

Answer (score 0):

Where did u export products.? If u export products from Manage Products grid, use 
`set_time_limit(0);`

this code on your export function.
It may be helpful to you,but i do not know that this is exact solution or not.

Comment: I am exporting products from admin system > import/export section